# Batch file for inserting macro's

Tags: excel, vba, file, batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file as icon on desktop, that would open a specific excel file, create a macro in it and copy code from a specific txt file into it.

The reason i need this, is that the file is located on a server and the ending .xlm cannot be cahanged (should not) so i cannot save it as a macro enabled file (to store a macro in it )

Could annyone with better understanding please explain to me how to create the said code ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unless access to the VBProject model is enabled, you can't do this with a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory it's possible by using the VBE object (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443984%28v=vs.60%29.aspx). But that's not activated by default so you can not ensure that each user is able to do that.

Better find other solutions for that problem. Can you upload .XLSB for example? Or do you have another kind of server available - for example a database server - you can use for storing the file? We use this method here for deploying our updates on AddIns and report templates for example.

Comment: I didnt phraze it right, we have a excel file that is stored on a server storage, a few people acess and edit that file, at the end of the day and external firm acess that file and their program reads data from it, they dont have IT guy or are just plain mean :) .... so they dont want to change the path to the file. For our editors i have wrote a simple macro that sums up data from all sheets inside that workbook but right now they have to copy file to their HDD and then edit workbook and copy macro, its annojing and time consuming and a problem to some who arentt that savy...

Comment: so i was thinking if there would be a possibility to make a batch file that would open that file, and create a macro and copy the macro code from a txt file that would be located on local PC into that macro.

Comment: as I said: in theory it's possible via VBE. But I still wouldn't go that way. Better to have one file already with a macro in it and import the data into that template file ... so going the other way. Don't bring the macro to the data ... bring the data to the macro.

Comment: Thanks, that was my second guess ... but this way its even more hassle than copying the macro everytime. Thank you.